# How to make a webpage stop loading and extract text from it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract the text from a url-shortner using this code :

```
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    os.environ['PATH'] += 'C:/Selenium Drivers'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get('https://pastebin.com/vkuagfwV')
    strings = str(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'textarea').text)
    strings = strings.replace("\n", " ")
    driver.close()
    
    print(strings)
```

But this code is not working until I manually stop the web-page from stop loading. I tried using XPATH as well but it didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to use str it's already a string.

Comment: Also it does work without the implicit wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `implicitly_wait` try using Expected Conditions `visibility_of_element_located` method here.
Also as mentioned in comments you don't need to use `str` casting there.
Please try this:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
os.environ['PATH'] += 'C:/Selenium Drivers'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://pastebin.com/vkuagfwV')
strings = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "textarea"))).text

strings = strings.replace("\n", " ")
driver.close()
    
print(strings)
```

**UPD**
Please add `eager` `pageLoadStrategy` configuration.

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

    
os.environ['PATH'] += 'C:/Selenium Drivers'
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://pastebin.com/vkuagfwV')
strings = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "textarea"))).text

strings = strings.replace("\n", " ")
driver.close()
    
print(strings)
```

Comment: still the same problem, the webpage is not stop loading neither the program is exiting with any error it is just running without doing anything until I am manually stopping the webpage from loading then it is printing the string.

Comment: OK, please see my updated answer

Comment: Hi thankyou it is working fine, one more quick question what is the meaning of depreciation warning and why I'm getting it with this code.

Comment: I guess I know what are you asking about :)
But please ask a new, separate question for that. I will try to hep there too if I will can.